# Bash - how to retrieve exit status of first command in an 'or' statement

Tags: bash, locust

In a script in gitlab I have the following statement:
 `locust || true`
This is because I don't want gitlab CI to stop the execution of the stage if the `locust` command fails with some exit code. But how can I nevertheless retrieve the exit code of the `locust` statement

Comment: Try `locust || echo locust exit code=$?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place the command in an `if` statement instead of using `|| true`, failure will not cause the script to exit and you'll be able to save the exit code.

```sh
if locust; then
    rc=0
else
    rc=$?
fi

echo locust exited with rc=$rc
```

PS: you can't just do `if ! locust; then...` because in that case, the `!` reverses the logic of the exit code. You actually need the `else` block for the `rc=$?` to work the way you want.

PPS: Yeah, I like that other answer better, `rc=0; locust || rc=$?`... I should have thought of that!

Comment: Thanks. I like both answers but yours actually seems more readable

Answer (score 2):

You could replace `true` with a variable assignment:

```sh
rc=0; locust || rc=$?
```

If like in a context with `errexit` set you want to make sure that the overall return code is always `0` even though the assignment miraculously fails somehow, just re-attach `|| true`:

```sh
rc=0; locust || rc=$? || true
```

---

Going further:

If instead of the literal `true` you want some next command to be executed if the first one fails, then negate `!` the variable assignment to make it fail in order to proceed to the evaluation of the second `||`.

```sh
# For personal use only!
rc=0; first-cmd || ! rc=$? || next-cmd
```

But be cautious here (as always when connecting commands logically): Don't use this shortcut in a production context! Rather perform separate checks to see if all preconditions have been met to execute that command.

Comment: Since `true` does nothing anyway, why not just `rc=0; locust || rc=$?`? I'm not sure how the assignment statement can fail, but if that's a risk, then `rc=0; locust || rc=$? || true` should *always* exit 0 *and* save locust's rc.

Comment: @joanis I thought `true` was just a placeholder for the next command.

Comment: No, I believe `|| true` is literally what's in the code. It's a common way to say "don't exit even if the command failed". It's relevant when you have `set -o errexit` earlier in your script.

Comment: @joanis I see. Ok, I'll adapt my answer to it. Thanks for suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the ”Locust side” of the question: you can pass `—exit-code-on-error 0` to only give a non-zero exit code if the run failed completely, not on failed responses.

(idk why this is not the default but changing it now would break stuff, so I probably won’t)

Comment: Thank you, so I presume it still quits bash if you use something like avg_response_time from locust plugins. Is there a way to continue execution if that fails as well?

Comment: avg_response_time’s main intended function is to set the exit code, so there is no way to disable that. But you could check explicitly for exit code 2 and ignore only that value.

Comment: thought so-thanks.